# Edit Mongodb array values to only contain alphabetic characters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to edit the data in my mongodb collection after importing the data from a csv file. One of my fields contains a mixture of alphabetic and numeric characters, and I want to edit it such that it only contains alphabetic characters to make querying easier

So I want to change this:

```
"categories" : [
    "9100005:1:factual",
    "9200041:2:arts_culture_and_the_media",
    "9200055:2:history"
]
```

Into this:

```
"categories" : [
    "factual",
    "arts culture and the media",
    "history"
]
```

I know that using $regex I can query for certain categories, so using:

```
db.bbc.find( { categories: {$regex: /factual/  }} )
```

I get all records with "factual" as a category, but I am unsure how to use $regex to query for multiple categories and I just feel avoiding using regular expressions entirely would be easier. Does anyone know what command I would have to run to be able to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 db.test1.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
        for(a in el.Category){
            print(el.Category[a].replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ""));
            el.Category[a]=el.Category[a].replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
        }
       db.test1.save(el); 
});
```

**Edit:**
To Preserve Space Just add space in regex.

You can use this line

```
el.Category[a].replace(/[^A-Za-z]*$/g, "");
```

To Handle Underscore

```
el.Category[a].replace(/[^A-Za-z_]*$/g, "");
```

Comment: It works in terms of removing all non-alphabetic characters, but now categories formed of more than one word, such as "arts culture and the media" appear as "artscultureandthemedia".  So I think your solution needs to be edited such that underscores are replaced by spaces.

Comment: @sums22 : you want to preserve space right ? or u want to preserve underscore ?

Comment: @sums22: see Edit

Comment: Spaces would be easier to handle I think. I suppose we could add an underscore to your regular expression and then just run a command to replace underscores with spaces right?

Comment: @sums22 :check answer :)

Comment: I ran your command but with an underscore in the regex to preserve underscores. I then ran this command to replace the underscores with spaces: 
db.things.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) { for(a in el.categories){ el.categories[a]=el.categories[a].replace("_", " "); } db.things.save(el);  });  which only replaces the first underscore. So "arts_culture_and_the_media" became "arts culture_and_the_media". How do I fix this?

Comment: @sums22 : use this `replace(/_/g, " ")` , what u have done will only replace first occurence

Comment: Sure why not! I just earned that privilege so might as well use it :D

Comment: that was for the help in comments ..heh heh